# How do i implement model or file for multiple cities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, inheritance

I want to make website for multiple cities.
for example:

Employee who works in NY login with their ID, that should be connected to

```
ny db.(NY : xxx.com/ny <- ny data only.)
```

Employee who works in TX login with their ID, that should be connected to

```
tx db.(NY : xxx.com/tx <- tx data only.)
```

Each state has same structure of database.
I am approaching inheritance of Db. is that correct way?

Comment: are you expecting just a yes or no answer, please rephrase your question to specifically resemble what you want in your answer. Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code/query. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Comment: Thank you for advice. since i am new here and still learning English. I will be better soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like **tenanting** might be the way to go.

Essentially you would add states* at the top level of your database, and then all your other models would `belong_to :state` at some appropriate level. Then, in the controllers and views, ensure your scopes include `where(state_id: current_user.state_id)`.

You can also specify parameters in your routes by prepending a colon to them in `config/routes.rb`, such as

```
get '/:state/login' => 'logins#new'
```

Then navigating to `xxx.com/ny/login` will set `params[:state]` to `'ny'` in the controller.

** I assume you mean states rather than cities, since you mention New York (NY) and Texas (TX).*